# Go programming linux amd64 wrong release object

Tags: linux, release, go, x86-64

I wanted to try-out go language from Google.

I've installed everything correctly like the doc said.
But when I try to compile I always have an output similar to this:

---

$ 6g main.go

main.go:3: import /home/manbear/gosource/pkg/linux_amd64/fmt.a: object is [linux amd64 weekly.2011-08-17 9569] expected [linux amd64 release.r59 9199+]

---

Before I had something like [linux amd64 release.r56 89** ], I tried to get the good release, but I don't seem to succeed in this quest.

Some advices would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I did try the "hg update release" but the problem why it did not fix the problem is because when I tried to fixed the release version previously; I had downloaded and installed on my Natty Ubuntu this:"golang_59-0~9199~oneiric1_amd64.deb".

I did not notice that it was for the next version of ubuntu (oneiric) [but it did install flawlessly though].

When I've noticed it in synaptic and delete it completly, recompile golang itself and everything is working now :)

An interesting fact, there is a package of "golang 59-0~9199-natty1" for Natty in the synaptic repository. I did not installed it since I've followed the general instruction for linux distributions. But I guess that it's possible to skip the compilation of the language itself and just install the package with apt-get install.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have compiled the latest weekly development build instead of the release version. Did you run the command:

```
hg update release
```

Before compiling (compiling Go itself I mean not your program) I think that should fix it for you.

Comment: It did update the release to .r59, but it's not enough. I still got this problem:                                                                                    object is [linux amd64 release.r59 9022] expected [linux amd64 release.r59 9199+]